# Watch response status every 2 seconds until it's completed or failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have to do runtime measurements on a website, that POSTS a xhr packet to the backend and then GETS a status every 2 seconds about the progress.
The xhr response body have `status` field such as `{status: "IN_PROGRESS"} {status:"IN_PROGRESS"}` or `{status:"FAILED"}` , `{status:"STARTED"` or `{status:"COMPLETED"}`.

My question is: How can I write a script that is watching the xhr traffic for a `status` package that is initializing the process and then watch the traffic for status xhr packages. If the status is failed or completed it should stop and print out failed or completed.

Comment: Is there only 1 Ajax request? Or there are multiple Ajax requests?

Comment: Looks like what you need is real-time technology, such as WebSocket, Comet etc.

Comment: @shaochuancs it's one POST request at the beginning and then every 2 seconds there is a GET request that's checking the status until a complete or failed comes back as the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send `GET` request every 2 seconds until a `COMPLETED` or `FAILED` comes back, you can store all XHR object into one pool. Once the status is `COMPLETED` or `FAILED`, stop the every-2-seconds timer and abort all XHR objects in the pool.

Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/test",
  data: "test data"
});

var xhrPool = [];
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/test-result",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.status === 'COMPLETED' || data.status === 'FAILED') {
        handleResponse(data);
      }
    }
  });
  xhrPool.push(xhr);
}, 2000);

function handleResponse(data) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  for (var i in xhrPool) {
    if (xhrPool[i].readyState !== 4) {
      xhrPool[i].abort();
    }
  }
}
```